# javascript my arc is not showing up or moving across the screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

hello i am trying to make a white circle move across a black box in javascript my circle is not showing up the big black box does but the circle does not show up i dont know why i am loading the page in google chrome here is the code

```
<html>
<head>

 <title>paddle</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
  <script>
  var canvas
  var canvasContext
  var ballX = 5
  window.onload = function() {

  var fps = 30;
  setInterval(updateAll, 1000)
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d")
 canvasContext.fillStyle = "black"
 canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
 }
 function updateAll() {

 ballX++

 canvasContext.fillStyle = "white";
 canvasContext.beginPath()
 canvasContext.arc(ballX, 100, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
 canvasContext.stroke()
 }


 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using stroke to draw the circle but you have not set the stroke style which is by default black. So you are drawing a black circle on a black background. Hence no see circle.

Also it is best to use `requestAnimationFrame` to animate rather than set interval.

Example animating a circle

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var ballX = 5;
var speed = 1
const radius = 10;
const fps = 30;
var frameCount = 0;

function animationLoop() {
    if (frameCount % (60 / fps) === 0) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black"
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        draw();
    }
    frameCount ++;
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);

}
function draw() {
    ballX = (ballX + speed) % (ctx.canvas.width + radius * 2);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(ballX - radius, 20, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="40"></canvas>
```